# How do I align text to middle within line-height

Tags: css, alignment

I wanted to put a large character to center alignment in both vertical and horizontal. here are my styles and result

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 150px auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: burlywood;
  line-height: 0.5;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div><span>s</span></div>
```

[here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIt5z.png)

How can I put the 's' in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the css difference is with `lower case` letters:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: burlywood;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  font-size: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div><span>S</span></div>
<div><span>s</span></div>
<div><span>M</span></div>
<div><span>m</span></div>
```